# To execute api call and window.open() onButton click but not care for api response

Tags: javascript

In my react project I need to, on click of button do a API call and navigate to another URL but should not wait for the response of the API call. like

```
const fnName = (siteUrl)=>{
 axios.post('https:xyz',payload);
 if(siteUrl){
  window.open(siteUrl);
 }
}
```

If I do as above the api call is not executing or is getting blocked in between. The api call is just a status call hence I do not want my users to wait for its response and navigate to the URL.
Is there any way I could do this instead of putting the window.open() in the API call's .then callback?

Comment: Couple of options, can you open the URL in new tab?
 If yes, API call would not be affected. If No, can you afford to miss the API call? If yes, consider a time duration for API call be fulfilled, for eg. 300 ms and redirect the user after 300 ms even if API is pending.

Comment: Thanks for your Input.Iam running this in webview within android app hence cannot open a new window and I cannot skip the API call since it is a post to a logger hence Iam not keen on the response of the logger. But giving a timeout  seems good. But my reason for asking this question is to see if there is a way my user need not wait after click of button, if there is a way to optimize.

Comment: Client can not execute any task once page is unloaded hence no way you can optimize/manage it from client-side. If you have a control over API layer, try to optimize it and try to reduce the response time.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you know the API call is being blocked. I feel you think so because the browser is opening a new url. But just so you are sure, you can add a `setTimeOut()` delay before running the `if` statement